# Why is my status bar different colors throughout my app?

Tags: swift, statusbar

Through my app, my status bar is different colors. I have not messed with the status bar at all in my code. On one screen, the status bar is black, with black letters and other times it is grey. What I figured out was that it was because of the background color. If the black ground color was clear then the status bar was black with black letters. If the background color was grey, then the status bar was grey with black letters. However, I still goes back and forth of the status bar being a the color of the background and the color of the uiview that is underneath it. For example, it the status bar shows up anywhere in my app with a color behind it, it drops the whole screen down 20 pixels. If it shows up over my uiview that I use a navigation bar, the screen starts at the very top underneath the uiview. Does any one what is causing this problem?

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots so that it's easier for us to see what's going on?

Comment: Done. I want it to look like the last one and not the first two.

Comment: There must be something set somewhere. There are 4 places I would check for any abnormalities: project settings, info.plist file, storyboard, and in code (view controllers and app delegate). Add more details if you find something suspicious.